# QMessageBox does not close when I click on X button

Tags: qt, user-interface, qmessagebox

I have following code

1) File dialog.h

```
class Dialog : public QDialog
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);

private slots:
    void questionMessage();
};
```

Case1:

2) dialog.cpp

```
void Dialog::questionMessage()
{
    QMessageBox::StandardButton reply;
    reply = QMessageBox::question(this, tr("QMessageBox::question()"),
                                MESSAGE,
                                QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No  );

    if (reply == QMessageBox::Yes)
        qDebug() << "Yes";
    else if (reply == QMessageBox::No)
       qDebug() << "No";
    else
       qDebug() << "Cancel";
  }
```

The issue is when I click on X mark at the top right then the QMessagebox does not get closed

Case2:

but If I have following code

```
void Dialog::questionMessage()
{
    QMessageBox::StandardButton reply;
    reply = QMessageBox::question(this, tr("QMessageBox::question()"),
               "MESSAGE",
               QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No |  QMessageBox::Cancel);       

    if (reply == QMessageBox::Yes)
        qDebug() << "Yes";
    else if (reply == QMessageBox::No)
       qDebug() << "No";
    else
       qDebug() << "Cancel";
  }
```

If I put QMessageBox::Cancel then it is working fine . It will be helpful if someone can guide me why I am not able to close QMessageBox with X in Case1

Comment: I just tried your code and I have not had the behavior you say.

Comment: Which version of qt you are using .

Comment: Qt 5.7.1  SO linux

Comment: There was a similar observation in another post, please look at the answer here: [Adding detailed text in QMessageBox makes close (X) button disabled](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24743691/4341198)